# Ghostscript error when saving .eps figure in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, eps

When trying to save a figure `plt.savefig('Figure.eps', dpi=300)`.

I encounter the error:

```
"Failed to find a Ghostscript installation.  Distillation step skipped."
```

Not sure what is going on. I am not able to open the subsequent .eps file.

Thanks and regards,
Sean

Comment: I thought there was a comment from someone else saying this but it seems to have disappeared so I'll ask it again; Do you actually have Ghostscript installed ?

Comment: Please, consider sharing more explicit  data regarding your local setup.

Comment: I downloaded "ghostpdl-9.56.1", but could not actually find a .exe or something inside that folder, which was unzipped using Winrar

Comment: The Windows Ghostscript executable is supplied as a Windows installer. Where did you download 'ghostpdl-9.56.1' from and what kind of file is it ? You can get the Windows release from here https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html If you want a different OS then you need to say what the OS is.

Comment: There is now a "gs" map under Program Files, but the error still persists. I could restart Anaconda. Or maybe I should add it to PATH?

Comment: You almost certainly need to add the binary to the $PATH environment variable, beyond that I can't tell you how Python finds Ghostscript. There is a Registry entry but I've no idea if it is used. In any event this isn't a Ghostscript question so I've removed the tag.